# How to rename the browser options in VS?

Tags: microsoft-edge, visual-studio-2019

[image: Browser list]
[image: Debug button]

I had the Edge Beta installed for a while and recently replaced the old Edge with Edge Stable. In the Visual Studio debug menu the browser shows up with the text `(2)` even though the Beta is now uninstalled and there's only one version of Edge on my system. How do I rename it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following steps:

1. Remove the browser options with text `(2)`.

   Click the `Browser With...` menu, select the browser option with the text `(2)`, click the "**Remove**" button to remove the selected option.

[image]

[image]

2. Add new browser options with custom Friendly name

   Click the "**Add**" button in the browser with window, in the popup window, click the "**...**" icon button to select the new browser launch file (the .exe file). Then, enter the custom Friendly name. After that, click "**OK**" button to save changes.

[image]

After the above steps, you can see the result as below:

[image]

Comment: doh, why didn't I think of removing and adding?! :D